# Cannot take user input in main java method

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

```
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInputs = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        loadCurrencyCodes();
        showCurrencies();
        findMyCurrency();
        
        System.out.print("Try again (Y/N): ");
        String yesNo = userInputs.next();
    }

}
```

Exception in thread "main" Try again (Y/N): java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at CheckCurrencyCode.main(CheckCurrencyCode.java:69)

I'm attempting to take in an input of y/n from the user, when I run the code I get the above exception.

Comment: Could you have created a new Scanner and closed it in one of your methods that you chose not to show us? Because once you close a scanner, you close the stream it uses automatically. And once you close System.in, it is almost impossible to open it again.

Comment: Ahh, actually that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should close object userInput object when its work is over :

```
System.out.print("Try again (Y/N): ");
String yesNo = userInputs.next();
userInputs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use try with resource and it will automatically handle closing stream for you.

```
   try(Scanner userInputs = new Scanner(System.in)){
         System.out.print("Try again (Y/N): ");
            String yesNo = userInputs.next();
     }
```